# EJB+Spring+Hibernate application

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I need to develop an application for just say,'user entry system' using EJB 3.0, spring and hibernate. Can any one guide me how to start it, or could suggest any site where can i get some sample application using combination of all three. or any person have some demo application . I am really in a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining EJB 3.0 and Spring is a bit unusual since these are competing and largely overlapping technologies.

Nevertheless Spring has a very strong [EJB integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html) that allows you to inject EJBs directly to Spring beans. There is no easy way to achieve this the other way around.

For the Hibernate part, you should have a look at JPA 1.0 (<strike>2.0 comes with EJB 3.1 I believe</strike>). Hibernate implements this standard, which is part of the EJB spec. JPA also seamlessly integrates with Spring: [*13.5 JPA*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa).

Comment: Lot of thanks to you sir, But i am new to Ejb and also nt did much in spring. So where could i get some sample application which integrate all three. I am going through EJB also right now

Comment: Good answer, but one small thing: JPA 2.0 does not come with EJB 3.1. JPA 2.0 is a completely seperate spec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use EJB with Spring unless you use MDBs. I would suggest you to use Spring+Hibernate+JPA(if needed).

Look into petclinic application provided by springsource. Here is an svn path.  Just search for 'Spring petclinic' for more details.

The svn location: *https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-javaconfig/trunk/samples/org.springframework.config.java.samples.petclinic*

Comment: K, thanks sir. I will go through it. And also inform me if get some source code

Comment: The link is cool, and apart for those who want to use combo as above can follow http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/35722/1954. This give a brief example

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use Spring with EJB, unless you mean Spring MVC. I would suggest you to use EJB+JPA+CDI(if needed).

Look into some Java EE 6 examples, for example look on the blogs of Adam Bien, BalusC and JDevelopment. They nicely show how easy and simple Java EE is.